# Many to many relationships not being cleaned up on destroy() in sequelize

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I have two models, User and Role.

```
var User = sequelize.define('User', {
    username:       { type:DataTypes.STRING, unique: true, allowNull: false },
    email:          { type:DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: false, unique: true },
    password:       { type:DataTypes.STRING, 
        set: function(v) {
            var salt = bcrypt.genSaltSync(10);
            console.log(v + ' ' + salt);
            var hash = bcrypt.hashSync(v, salt);
            this.setDataValue('password', hash);
        } 
    },
    token:          {type:DataTypes.STRING, allowNull:true, unique: false }
},{
    associate: function(models)
    {
        User.hasMany(models.Role);
    }
});


var Role = sequelize.define('Role', {
    rolename:       { type:DataTypes.STRING, unique: true, allowNull: false }
}, {
    associate: function(models)
    {
        Role.hasMany(models.User);
    }
});
```

As you can see a user can have many roles. These are of course joined in a many to many table.

The problem is that if I remove a user from the database like so:

```
    db.User.find( { where: {username:username}, include:[db.Role]} )
        .success( function(user) {
            db.Role.find( {where: {}})
            user.destroy()
                            ...
```

The user record is in fact destroyed but the roles related to that user are orphaned in the RoleUsers table. What is the recommended best practice in the framework for removing them?

Answer (score 0):

Currently we support `onDelete` and `onUpdate` constraints for relations in sequelize. However in does not currently work for many to many. If you post a feature request at https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues i might have time to look at it soon